Mininet fails to configure resource limits in LXC container
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server with LXD on it, and I use the following command to create my container:

sudo lxc init ubuntu:22.04 <container_name>

Then I set the container to be privileged.
After this, I install in the container the P4 related software following this link: https://github.com/jafingerhut/p4-guide/blob/master/bin/README-install-troubleshooting.md
The script inside this repo successfully installs all P4 related tools as well as Mininet. However, when I run one of the P4 examples downloaded from the repo I have the following error:

*** Error setting resource limits. Mininet's performance may be affected.

The P4 program works fine, but for my experiments I require a higher performance from my P4 switch than the one currently in the container.
Additional information:

The profile and the container have no CPU, memory or network limitations imposed on them. I haven't set any limitation, and no such limitation appears in the profile and container configuration
The container's network type is a bridge.
This Mininet error comes from the function fixLimits() in file mininet/util/utils.py
This error message does not appear when installing directly on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM.

Does anyone know how to address this error and improve the performance of a Mininet emulated network inside LXC/D?
